# iCarousel get user tapped index

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I want to get the index that user has tapped.I have tried several ways to detect it but none of it is working.
Here is what I have tried.

```
   func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) {
        print("this has been tapped from Carousel \(index)")
    }

    func carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange(carousel: iCarousel) {
        let index=carousel.currentItemIndex
        print("this is current index \(index) ")
    }

    func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let webV:WKWebView!
        webV = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 250))
        if let updatedResource = myDict[index+1]{//name of resource I want to load
            let url =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(updatedResource, withExtension: "html")
            let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
            webV.loadRequest(requestObj);
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: Selector("tapDetected"))
            //tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
            tapGesture.enabled = true
            webV.userInteractionEnabled = true
            webV.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

           // setUserInteractionEnabled = true
            print("this has been rendered \(index)")
          }
        return webV

    }

    func tapDetected(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        print("yes tap has been detected :)")
```

Comment: Supposed the tap detected at `didSelectItemAtIndex` method. Have you set the delegate?

Comment: @cod3rite, after I have set the delegate the Carousel shows either the first or the last record.

Comment: is the tap detected?

Comment: No but `carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange` is getting called

Comment: `didSelectItemAtIndex` also get called?

Comment: No unfortunately that is not being called :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not help since I'm using the Objective-C but the tap is getting detected in the

```
- (void)didTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
```

method.

```
 [_delegate carousel:self didSelectItemAtIndex:index];
 NSLog(@"Selected app at index: %d", index);
```

works as expected.  I'm using iCarousel version 1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (note the _ flag for anonymous parameter)

```
func carousel (_ carousel: iCarousel, didSelectItemAt index: Int) {

}
```